# How can I get rsync to show only error messages AND a summary?

Tags: rsync

I use rsync to backup a few thousands of files and pipe the output to a file.
Given the number of files I'd like to see a list of only those transfers that had issues as well as a summary to show which completed.

So, using the `-q` flag displays nicely by exception any error only.
Using `--stats` shows a helpful summary at the end.

The problem is that I cannot combine them because it appears that `-q` suppresses the stats output.

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Are you using `-v`? If so, have you tried not using that? Maybe post the entire command you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will help someone else. In the end the only thing that worked was to swap the output as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415187).
So in my case it was simply redirecting as follows: 
    2>> /output.log >> /output.log

Comment: This is perfect for my case where I'm rsyncing with ssh and a key that requires a passphrase. This allows for logging but also for entering the passphrase. What I had before was only logging the request for the passphrase and hanging, i.e. `> /var/log/rsync.log 2>&1`, this on the other hand solves my problem, I can enter my passphrase and have logging too! My command looks like: `time rsync -avz --delete -e "ssh -i /root/.key" ec2-user@some-ip-addr:/apps/app /apps/new-app 2>> /apps/new-app-rsync.log >> /apps/new-app-rsync.log`

Answer (score 18):

**This did the trick for me :**

```
rsync -azh --stats <source> <destination>
```

- `-a`/`--archive`: archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
- `-z`/`--compress`: compress file data during the transfer
- `-h`/`--human-readable`: output numbers in a human-readable format
- `--stats`: give some file-transfer stats